# Geocoding: Match address is doubling up text

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, address, text

I'm geocoding some addresses, and using our address data as the locator service's reference. The oddest thing is happening, though, which I've never encountered. The 'Match Address' address is doubling up the street names - giving me a lower Match percentage.
 I'm attaching some photos - if you can give some insight on how I can correct it, it would be a huge help!
[image]

As you can see, the Match_Addr is taking the address entered in from Addr field, and doubling it up. It's finding an address and giving me a 100% Score, but keeps the Status as Tied.

Comment: I think we may need some more information. What geocoder are you using? Is it on a GIS platform?

Comment: I'm using a geocoder that we built using our internal address point data, and I am using it on a GIS platform. The address data itself doesn't have this repeating text, and its never happened before.

Comment: Looks like your geocoder software is returning the name+fullname as Match_addr from your internal address point data.  Check with your geocoder developer.